# scalability of azure cloud queue

Tags: wcf, azure, azure-storage, servicebus

In current project we currently use 8 worker role machines side by side that actually work a little *different* than azure may expect it.

Short outline of the system:

- each worker start up to 8 processes that actually connect to cloud queue and processes messages
- each process accesses three different cloud queues for collecting messages for different purposes (delta recognition, backup, metadata)
- each message leads to a WCF call to an ERP system to gather information and finally add retreived response in an ReDis cache
- this approach has been chosen over many smaller machines due to costs and performance. While 24 one-core machines would perform by 400 calls/s to the ERP system, 8 four-core machines with 8 processes do over 800 calls/s.

Now to the question: when even increasing the count of machines to increase performance to 1200 calls/s, we experienced outages of Cloud Queue. In same moment of time, 80% of the machines' processes don't process messages anymore.

Here we have two problems:

1. Remote debugging is not possible for these processes, but it was possible to use [dile](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dile/) to get some information out.
2. We use GetMessages method of Cloud Queue to get up to 4 messages from queue. Cloud Queue always answers with 0 messages. Reconnect the cloud queue does not help.

Restarting workers does help, but shortly lead to same problem.
Are we hitting the natural end of scalability of Cloud Queue and should switch to Service Bus?

*Update*:

I have not been able to fully understand the problem, I described it in [the natual borders of Cloud Queue](http://codingsoul.de/2016/01/25/the-natural-borders-of-cloud-queue-scalability/).

To summarize:

- Count of TCP connections have been impressive. Actually too impressive (multiple hundreds)
- Going back to original memory size let the system operate normally again

Answer (score 1):

In my experience I have been able to get better raw performance out of Azure Cloud Queues than service bus, but Service Bus has better enterprise features (reliable, topics, etc).  Azure Cloud Queue should process up to 2K/second per queue.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-scalability-targets/

You can also try partitioning to multiple queues if there is some natural partition key.

Make sure that your process don't have some sort of thread deadlock that is the real culprit.  You can test this by connecting to the queue when it appears hung and trying to pull messages from the queue.  If that works it is your process, not the queue.

Also take a look at this to setup some other monitors:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-monitor-storage-account/

Comment: Actually better performance was the reason why we chosen Cloud queue over ServiceBus also. We never hit 2k/s with 8 workers by 8 processes getting max. 4 messages from my point of view - in worse case that would just be less than 300 calls. I personally believe the count of open TCP connections cannot be maintained by the OS anymore. It is also very strange that there is no exception at all. Just no messages. :-(. Anyway thanks for the links!

Answer (score 0):

It took some time to solve this issue:

First a summarization of the usage of the storage account:

- We used the blob storage once a day pretty heavily.
- The "normal" diagonistics that Azure provides out of the box also used the same storage account.
- Some controlling processes used small tables to store and read information once an hour for ca. 20 minutes
- There may be up to 800 calls/s that try to increase a number to count calls to an ERP system.

When recognizing that the storage account is put under heavy load we split it up.

- Now there are three physical storage accounts heaving 2 queues.
- The original one still keeps up to 800/s calls for increasing counters
- Diagnositics are still on the original one
- Controlling information has been also moved

The system runs now for 2 weeks, working like a charm. There are several things we learned from that:

- No, the infrastructure is "not just there" and it doesn't scale endlessly.
- Even if we thought we didn't use "that much" summarized we used quite heavily and uncontrolled.
- There is no "best practices" anywhere in the net that tells the complete story. Esp. when start working with the storage account a guide from MS would be quite helpful

Exception handling in storage is quite bad. Even if the storage account is overused, I would expect some kind of exception and not just returning zero message without any surrounding information 
Read complete story here: [natural borders of cloud storage scalability](http://codingsoul.de/2016/01/25/the-natural-borders-of-cloud-queue-scalability/)

UPDATE: 
The scalability has a lot of influences. You may are interested in [Azure Service Bus: Massive count of listeners and senders](http://codingsoul.de/2016/06/22/azure-service-bus-scalability-with-massive-count-of-listeners/) to be aware of some more pitfalls.